# Don't run this sed when a string is matched?

Tags: text-processing, sed, osx

I have this `sed` command for deleting numbers inside of tags:

```
sed 's/\(<[^0-9>]*\)[0-9]*\([^0-9]*>\)/\1\2/g'
```

But does anyone know how I can exclude certain strings from this?

Now it would so something like this, input:

```
<user1></user1>
<password2></password2>
```

And output:

```
<user></user>
<password></password>
```

However, I want to be able to exclude certain strings, like password2 for example, then the output would be like this:

```
<user></user>
<password2></password2>
```

Comment: [Don't try to parse it with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/836748).

Comment: @AaronD.Marasco, there's a tacit rule on U&L that before posting a link to that SO Q&A, you must answer the question without using a regex.

Comment: @AaronD.Marasco I have seen that many times, it's such a stupid answer. It doesn't say why you shouldn't parse it with regex, just "don't parse it with regex".

Comment: @DisplayName read any of the other highly voted answers for better explanations of why you shouldn't do it. Alternatively, have look at [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4234491/1081936) of how to do it correctly. Unless you can write something like that, avoid parsing anything except the most simple HTML with regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

You could preprocess your file to insert a special character for those strings you want to whitelist to prevent them for being replaced.

Like you'd change:

```
<user1></user1>
<password2></password2>
```

To

```
<user1></user1>
<|password2><|/password2>
```

first and use `s/\(<[^|0-9>]*\)[0-9]*\([^0-9]*>\)/\1\2/g` for the substitution. If `|` may already occur in the input, you can escape them using a scheme like: `_` -> `_u`, `|` -> `_p` which you'd undo afterwards.

```
sed '
  s/_/_u/g;s/|/_p/g
  s:<\(/\{0,1\}password2>\):<|\1:g
  s:<\(/\{0,1\}othertag>\):<|\1:g
  s/\(<[^|0-9>]*\)[0-9]*\([^0-9]*>\)/\1\2/g
  s/|//g;s/_p/|/g;s/_u/_/g'
```